# nvm: command not found with Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, nvm

I am running a Jenkins job to kick off a deployment. This Jenkins job kicks off a Jenkins file within the app its trying to deploy. While its running it cannot seem to find nvm to continue. I found a couple cases on here.. mostly with sourcing out the .nvm location, but that doesnt seem to work for me.  I can log onto the Jenkins server and verify nvm is installed and does work... with both my account and when I sudo in as proxy. Here is my latest Jenkinsfile script up to where it fails:

```
 def environment = ['develop', 'test', 'production']

 pipeline {
   agent {label 'APP-01'}

      stages {

        stage("Checkout") {
          when {anyOf {branch 'develop'; branch 'PR-*' } }
           steps {
             checkout scm
           }

       stage("Dependencies - npm installs") {
          when {anyOf {branch 'develop'; branch 'PR-* } }
            steps {
               sh 'pwd' 
               sh 'echo $PATH'
               sh '. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh'
               sh 'nvm list'
```

Jenkins Console Output:

Starting with failed section...

```
 [Pipeline] { (Dependencies - npm installs)
 [Pipeline] sh
 + pwd
 /data/1/apps/jenkins/workspaces/workspace/jects_APP01_Repos_app-ui_develop

 [Pipeline] sh
 + export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/proxy/.nvm
 + PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/proxy/.nvm
 [Pipeline] sh
 + . /home/proxy/.nvm/nvm.sh
 ++ '[' '!' -d '' ']'
 ++++ dirname /home/proxy/.nvm/nvm.sh
 +++ cd /home/proxy/.nvm
 +++ pwd
 ++ export NVM_DIR=/home/proxy/.nvm
 ++ NVM_DIR=/home/proxy/.nvm
 ++ '[' -x '' ']'
 ++ nvm ls default
 ++ nvm use default
 ++ '[' 2 -lt 1 ']'
 +++ nvm_version default
 ++++ nvm_ls default
 ++++ local PATTERN=default
 +++++ cd /home/proxy/.nvm
 ++++ echo N/A
 ++++ return
 ++ VERSION=N/A
 ++ echo N/A
 +++ '[' N/A= N/A ']'
 +++ return
 ++ VERSION=N/A
 ++ echo 'N/A version is not installed yet'
 ++ return 1
 ++ true
 [Pipeline] sh
 + nvm list
 /data/1/apps/jenkins/workspaces/workspace/jects_APP01_Repos_app-ui_develop@tmp/durable-2d17a47f/script.sh: line 1: nvm: command not found
```

Comment: I'm not sure about nodejs and nvm. Is it the same? I mean if you install nodejs will it install nvm for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that every time you run an `sh` command, it's as if you were opening a new terminal window.
As a result, if you add the nvm location to your path with one `sh` step, your path will be changed only for that shell session, and when you run another `sh` command it will create a new session and use the old path.

A way to work around this is to use a single `sh` step for sourcing and using `nvm`, like this:

```
sh script: '''\
  pwd
  echo $PATH
  . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
  nvm list'''.stripIndent()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Had no idea each sh had its own session. Thanks for the learning today!

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck Run script on SandBox, Approve this script and add below:

```
sh ". /var/lib/jenkins/.bash_rc && nvm use ${nodeVersion}"
```